# Inserção simultâneas de itens e vendas com C#, Windows Forms e PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

Ola, Estou desenvolvendo uma tela de vendas em C# Windows Forms. Estou recém no inicio do projeto, porém me deparei com uma situação onde não tenho certeza do que fazer. Estou usando um banco de dados PostgreSQL, criei uma tabela chamada VENDA e outra ITENSVENDA. A lógica que estou usando é a seguinte: Ao inserir o primeiro produto cria uma linha na tabela VENDA gerando um código que é do tipo SERIAL. Em seguida esse código é armazenado e utilizado para inserir os itens dessa venda na tabela ITENSVENDA. É ai que vem o problema, quando houver mais de uma máquina inserindo ao mesmo tempo pode dar problema de inserir itens com COD da venda errada, se acontecer de gravar várias vendas ao mesmo tempo, justamente porque preciso recuperar o código da minha venda que estou  fazendo em minha máquina. Qual é a melhor forma de eu resolver esse problema? o fazer para não acabar lançando itens em em vendas diferentes da minha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa abrir uma transação, no primeiro insert retorna o código que foi inserido e depois utiliza ele pra inserir os itens.

Se ocorrer tudo bem, executa o Commit, caso contrário, RollBack.

Exemplo:

```
using (NpgsqlConnection conexao = new NpgsqlConnection())
{
    conexao.Open();
    using (NpgsqlTransaction transacao = conexao.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            string codigoVenda;
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmdInser = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into [tabela]... returning id", conexao, transacao))
            {
                using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmdInser.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dr.Read();
                    codigoVenda = dr[0].ToString();
                }

            }


            List<string> itens = new List<string>(); //apensa simulando uma lista de itens

            foreach (string item in itens)
            {
                //item.VendaId = codigoVenda; //Atribui o código da venda no item

                using (NpgsqlCommand cmdItem = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into [tabela]...", conexao, transacao))
                {
                    cmdItem.ExecuteScalar();
                }

            }


            //ocorreu tudo certo
            transacao.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            //deu erro
            transacao.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```